# Network Error in Expo React-Native App (android)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to `fetch` data from remote server and my domain is `https://abcd.com:3000`.

I've several endpoints but in different device different endpoints are giving `[TypeError: Network request failed]`.

I further debugged and found this is the error `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`.

My request looks like this:

```
let url = `https://abcd.com:3000/packages/featured`
const response= await axios.get(url)
console.log(response)
```

I've found several solution for native `android` but no luck for `expo`.